# how to run a vmdk image on another 64 bit machine which does not have vt support

Tags: vmware-vmdk

I have a CentOS 64 as Guest OS installation (basically the vmdk file) which was created on a machine which had Virtualization Support enabled in BIOS.
How ever I have another machine where I do not have virtualization support (even in BIOS) both these machines are 64 bit.

When ever I try to boot the vmd image which was created on machine with Virtualization support on the other machine which does not have virt support
after going through a series of messages as

```
You have configured this virtual  machine to use a 64 bit guest Operating System.How ever 64 bit operation is not possible. This host does not support VT.For more detailed information see http://vmware.com/info?id=152
Continue without 64 bit support.
```

Where I select yes and then some boot sequence starts but then I see a message

```
Your CPU does not support long  mode.Use a 32 bit distribution.
```

Is there a way to get past it.Given this another machine is a 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like it is [possible](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=vmdk+virtualbox) to import VMDK images into VirtualBox, which can run without VT albeit a little slower.

Comment: Ok after your suggestion I downloaded virtualbox from here  http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads for Ubuntu the version  I have is 4.0 and following page says some instructions as how vmdk images can run
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-convert-vmware-image-to-virtualbox-image.html how ever I do not have any such option to import the vmx file or vmdk image in Virtualbox.So any other suggestion.

Comment: You don't really "import" it. You need to create a new VM in VirtualBox, and when you get to the part where you configure the virtual disk, you can choose an existing disk file. VMDK is one of the supported formats.

Answer (score 1):

If you either have a very early 64bit chip or are (un)lucky enough (like me) to have a more recent non-VT Intel chip, there's one course of action remaining: EMULATION.

Bochs & Qemu will emulate the 64bit chip hardware, and there are a couple of decent GUI's for managing it. Finding a stable Qemu environment in your preferred distro might entail turning off some chipset features, or backing through some qemu versions or bios binaries.

Bochs is slower than Qemu. Qemu has the fast driver-mode KQemu, but consider it still like running a modern OS on a 200Mhz 1-core processor.